# How to couple or decouple actions that may deliver inputs and outputs to each other

Tags: design-patterns

Consider this - I have Action A with output OA, and action B that can use OA but not mandatory (let's say it is statically determined on system start up with Dependency Injection)

What would be the best design pattern for this? (consider there would be Action C that can take OA and\or OB etc.)

in what level (and how) the code should know that the active chain is  A --> OA --> B or  A --> B ? is it like factory that a concrete class will implement this "pipeline"?

Comment: Too abstract, can you provide a bit of pseudo code or a class diagram? Do (or can) your "Actions" share a common base class or interface?  Same question for your output (which is really also an input).  Looks like `Pipes and Filers` pattern to me but I await more details for further elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to describe an [Observer design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). An alternative/improvement to this pattern is called [signals and slots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signals_and_slots). Qt has a nice implementation of it also, [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html).